# How to assign a route present in index.js file from hbs?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I want to refer my signout menu item which is defined under views folder as myprofile.hbs to a route /logout defined inside index.js

I tried pasting the path into a href= of that file.

//Present inside views/myprofile.hbs

```
<li>
<a href="./index.js/logout">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" id="signout"></i>
Sign Out </a>
</li>
```

//present inside index.js

```
app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the above `app.get()` is at the root of your application, that `href` just needs to be `/logout`.

```
<a href="/logout">
```

matching your path in Express:

```
app.get("/logout"), . . .
```

Comment: oh thanx it was so simple I don't know where I was stuck .lol